# No model binding with editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, mvc-editor-templates

I have following view:

```
@model StockItemDetailModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditDetails", "StockItem"))
{
    <div class="ItemDetails">
        <table class="datagrid">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">@Model.StockItemPropertiesCaption</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">@Model.StoreLabel</td>
                <td class="value">@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Store)</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">@Model.BuildingLabel</td>
                <td class="value">@Html.DevExpress().TextBoxFor(model => model.Building).GetHtml()</td>
                <td class="validationError">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Building)</td>
            </tr>

...

             <tr>
                <td colspan="3">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountModel, "Amounts")</td>
>            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="validationError">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountModel)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr />
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="@Model.SaveButtonLabel" />
}
```

The partial View "Amounts" is as follows:

```
@model AmountModel

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">@Model.AmountLabel</td>
        <td class="value">
            @Html.DevExpress().SpinEditFor(model => model.DenormalizedNetAmount,
                    settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "DenormalizedNetAmount";
                        settings.Width = 153;
                        settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = @"0.0,0";
                        settings.Number = 0;
                    }).GetHtml()
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            @Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(model => model.NetAmountUnit,
                    settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "NetAmountUnit";
                        settings.Width = 60;
                    }).BindList(args => this.Model.AllUnits, args => this.Model.AllUnits).GetHtml()
        </td>
    </tr>

...

    </table>
```

This is the AmountModel:

```
        public class AmountModel
        {
            public decimal DenormalizedNetAmount { get; set; }
            public string NetAmountUnit { get; set; }

...

            public string AmountLabel
            {
                get { return i18n.StockItemDetailModel_AmountLabel; }
            }

...
        }
```

But the values of the input fields are not in the model in the Controller created by the model binder.
Why does the model binder not recognize the values in the editor template?

When I passed the FormCollection the values where correctly passed under the names "AmountModel.~"

```
public ActionResult EditDetails(FormCollection collection)
{
var netamount = collection["AmountModel.DenormalizedNetAmount"]; //correct value!

...

}
```

Comment: Show rendered html please. Binding use params that posted to server. And post use `name` attribute of inputs.

Comment: Why you do not contact the DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: @teovankot the name attribute is like "AmountModel.DenormalizedNetAmount" etc. (see my edited question)

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** specify the **Name** property when using the strong-typed (***For) helpers.

See the [MVC Data Editors - Model Binding and Editing](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=KA18701) learning resource on the DevExpress forum.

Comment: I tried it without the name property, but it still doesn't work